# A Ruby on Rails has_many relationship.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm new to RoR and working on my first project. The basic concept behind the idea is to connect "Users" that have chosen a set a "Skills" with other Users that that have submitted a "Help Request" that deals specifically with those chosen skills. An app that connects Skilled Users with Users that need help if you will. My question has to do with the relationship between the Users, Skills, and Help_Request Models. It feels like a "has_many :through association" or maybe "polymorphic association" might be in order for this kind of three way relationship? Really not sure?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest structure would be a HABTM between Users/Skills and HelpRequest/Skills, that you then join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid ShivamD's answer will not suffice. That would require duplicate `Skills`, and queries the relevant `User.help_requests` via relationship, where instead you need an intersection.

Not just that, `Users` who create `HelpRequests` will already have a `has_many` relationship. That makes sense.

I won't include schema for the `HABTM` I'm about to suggest (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)), but I will cover the models. Essentially what you want:

```
skill = Skill.create(name: "My Skill")
user.skills         << skill
help_request.skills << skill

user.matched_help_requests
#> [help_request]
```

Which can be achieved as follows:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

  def matched_help_requests
    HelpRequest.joins(:skills).where("skills.id IN(?)", skills.pluck(:id))
  end
end

class HelpRequest
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :help_requests
end
```

---

EDIT: here's the schmea for the `HABTM`:

```
rails g migration add_skills_join_tables
```

#### within migration

```
def change
  create_table :skills_users, id: false do |t|
    t.references :skill
    t.references :user
  end

  create_table :help_requests_skills, id: false do |t|
    t.references :skill
    t.references :help_request
  end

  add_index :skills_users,        [:skill_id, :user_id]
  add_index :help_request_skills, [:skill_id, :help_request_id] 
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify. As I'm setting up my HABTM relationships do I create one or two join tables without a primary key? (as indicated in the documentation) Also, would you mind explaining the "matched_help_request" method just a little bit more? Thanks a ton Damien, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Flint285 You'll require two join tables. See tiagotex's answer. The two tables you'll need are `skills_users` and `help_requests_skills`, and neither have a primary key, but they do have indexes. I'll update my answer to show the migration.

Comment: @Flint285 updated answer. The `matched_help_request` method could possibly be improved. What this does is collect the user's skill ids via the join table skills_users (`skills.pluck(:id)`), then performs a join query where `HelpRequest` skill ids match.

Comment: Ok, have my schemea and models all ready to go. Would you mind explaining the "Skill.create" method just a little bit more and how that fits into the controller and the view? As usual, thanks a bunch Damien.

Answer (score 1):

A polymorphic association is when a model should belong to another model. Let's say when you a comment model. You can comment on a post and a comment itself. That's when you would use a polymorphic.

In your case a simple has_many through would do. 
It should look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :skills 
  has_many :help_requests, through: :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :helpRequest
end

class HelpRequest < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :skills 
  has_many :users, through :skills
end
```

For more information the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 0):

One hay is to create a `has_and_belongs_to_many`relation between the Users and Helprequests and Skills, so you end up with this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Help_request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skills < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
      has_and_belongs_to_many :help_requests
end
```

Then you need to create the tables

```
 rails g migration add_skills_users_table

 rails g migration add_help_requests_skills_table
```

In the end run `rake db:migrate`

You can then search for it using `User.first.skills`

Comment: Just to clarify. As I'm setting up my HABTM relationships do I create one or two join tables without a primary key?